# QThread is not emitting signal even after run() finished

Tags: python, multithreading, qt, pyqt5, qthread

When User clicks on "Update" Push Button, box_updatetool_fcn will be executed. MainThread will update the Progressbar in the QMainWindow while the other QThread will download the file. But it executes perfectly, but the problem is signal emited by the WorkerThread is not updating immediately.

Even I have gone through many questions, none solved my problem. I don't know why my **fcn_qthread_output** is not executing immediately after Qthread finished.

Even the QThread finished() function also executing after the Main Function finished, which I am not using in my current program. I don't know what's wrong in the program, is something missing?

Here is the following console output -

```
Run Function Closed 
Out1 : False, FileName 
Main Function Ended 
Out2 : True, FileName
```

What I am expecting is -

```
Run Function Closed 
Out2 : True, FileName 
Out1 : True, FileName
Main Function Ended
```

Below is the program execution flow -

```
class WorkerThread(QtCore.QThread):
    outResult = QtCore.pyqtSignal(tuple)
    def __init__(self,target,args,parent=None):
        super(WorkerThread, self).__init__(parent)
        self.fcn  = target
        self.args = args
    
    def run(self):
        outResult = self.fcn(*self.args)
        self.outResult.emit(outResult)
        print('Run Function Closed')

class ApplicationWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def box_updatetool_fcn(self):
        t1 = WorkerThread(target=self.boxapi.fcn_downloadfile, args=(fileID,)) #ThreadWithResult
        t1.outResult.connect(self.fcn_qthread_output)
        t1.start()
        self.box_pbar_fcn(tempfilename,fsize)
        print(f'Out1 : {self.var_box_output}')
        self.boxapi.fcn_updatetool(file_fullpath,self.progpath)
        print('Main Function Ended')
    
    def fcn_qthread_output(self,result):
        self.var_box_output = result
        print(f'Out2 : {self.var_box_output}')

    def box_pbar_fcn(self,filename,fullsize):
        pobj = self.ui.progressbar
        while(barprogress < 100):
        if os.path.exists(filename):
            currfilesize = os.path.getsize(filename)
            barprogress  = int(currfilesize/fullsize*100)
            pobj.setValue(barprogress)
```

Reproducible Code -

I have used **box_pbar_fcn** (progress bar which shows the downloading progress) and **t1 Thread** (downloading the file) will Run in simultaneously.

```
import os, sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore

class WorkerThread(QtCore.QThread):
    outResult = QtCore.pyqtSignal(tuple)
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        super(WorkerThread, self).__init__(parent)

    def run(self):
        outResult = (True,'Out1')
        self.outResult.emit(outResult)
        print('Run Function Closed')

class ApplicationWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.var_box_output = (False,'Inp1')
        self.box_updatetool_fcn()
        
    def box_updatetool_fcn(self):
        tempfilename,fsize = 'Test',300
        t1 = WorkerThread() #ThreadWithResult
        t1.outResult.connect(self.fcn_qthread_output)
        t1.start()
        self.box_pbar_fcn(tempfilename,fsize)
        print(f'Out1 : {self.var_box_output}')
        print('Main Function Ended')
    
    def fcn_qthread_output(self,result):
        self.var_box_output = result
        print(f'Out2 : {self.var_box_output}')

    def box_pbar_fcn(self,filename,fullsize):
        pass
        #pobj = self.ui.progressbar
        #while(barprogress < 100):
        #if os.path.exists(filename):
        #   currfilesize = os.path.getsize(filename)
        #   barprogress  = int(currfilesize/fullsize*100)
        #   pobj.setValue(barprogress)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mw = ApplicationWindow()
    mw.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Using that while loop that waits until the thread is finished makes the usage of a thread completely useless. Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and improve your indentation by checking how to [properly format your code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362)

Comment: @musicamante Yes, i am not using the while loop inside box_updatetool_fcn Function (it is shown - both functions are simultaneous depend on downloading function execution), but i am using while loop in box_pbar_fcn Function to show the progress of downloading file

Comment: The point of providing reproducible examples is that they not only reproduce the result of your issue, but also the same behavior. Blocking a thread until *another* is completed completely nullifies the purpose of the other thread, but if you don't do it like that then we cannot reproduce *your* issue.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are blocking the main thread with your while True (There should never be an instruction that blocks the eventloop for long). In Qt the logic is to do the job asynchronously. In this case I suspect that in a thread you are downloading a file and you want to show the download progress in the QProgressBar and for this you are continuously measuring the size of the file. If so, a possible solution is to use a QTimer to run the periodic task of measuring the file size.

Disclaimer: The following code that has not been tested should work. As I do not know how is the way you save the file, it could be that it does not work since many functions only write the file at the end and not in parts for efficiency reasons.

```py
import os
import sys
from functools import cached_property

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Downloader(QtCore.QThread):
    outResult = QtCore.pyqtSignal(tuple)

    def run(self):
        import time

        time.sleep(10)
        outResult = (True, "Out1")
        self.outResult.emit(outResult)
        print("Run Function Closed")


class FileObserver(QtCore.QObject):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self._filename = ""
        self._current_size = 0

    @property
    def filename(self):
        return self._filename

    def start(self, filename, interval=100):
        self._current_size = 0
        self._filename = filename
        self.timer.setInterval(interval)
        self.timer.start()

    def stop(self):
        self.timer.stop()

    @cached_property
    def timer(self):
        timer = QtCore.QTimer()
        timer.timeout.connect(self._measure)
        return timer

    def _measure(self):
        if os.path.exists(self.filename):
            file_size = os.path.getsize(filename)
            if self._current_size != file_size:
                self._current_size = file_size
                self.file_size_changed.emit(file_size)


class ApplicationWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.var_box_output = (False, "Inp1")
        self.box_updatetool_fcn()

    @cached_property
    def file_observer(self):
        return FileObserver()

    def box_updatetool_fcn(self):
        tempfilename, fullsize = "Test", 300
        self.ui.progressbar.setMaximum(fullsize)

        t1 = WorkerThread(self)
        t1.outResult.connect(self.fcn_qthread_output)
        t1.finished.connect(self.file_observer.stop)
        t1.start()

        self.file_observer.start(tempfilename, interval=10)

    def fcn_qthread_output(self, result):
        self.var_box_output = result
        print(f"Out2 : {self.var_box_output}")

    def box_pbar_fcn(self, file_size):
        self.ui.progressbar.setValue(file_size)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mw = ApplicationWindow()
    mw.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I am not using while loop in main thread, so edited my question. But inorder to show the progress, I am checking file size continuously using while loop in main thread. Instead of while loop, again do need to use qtimer to check file status ?

Comment: @ChandraSekharK 1) in the code that I base on my post you did it so do not point out inconsistencies 2) The action of measuring is a task, and like any task it must be asynchronous: an event must invoke it, in this case the event is the triggering of a QTimer, what event do you want to use?